NextIntl CreateMiddleware don't set NEXT_LOCALE cookie as secure
I've started a NextJs project and when I follow the docs I realize that in production the cookie NEXT_LOCALTE generated by the Intl middleware is not set as secure?
How can I improve that? I've created an approach but I don't know if that the best solution.
Original
import createMiddleware from "next-intl/middleware";
import { locales } from "./i18n.config";

export default createMiddleware({
    defaultLocale: locales[0],
    locales,
    localeDetection: true,
});

export const config = {
    matcher: [
        "/((?!api|_next|_vercel|.*\\..*).*)",
    ],
};

Approach to avoid the issue:
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import createIntlMiddleware from 'next-intl/middleware';
import { locales } from './i18n.config';

const intlMiddleware = createIntlMiddleware({
    defaultLocale: locales[0],
    locales,
    localeDetection: true,
});

export function middleware(req: NextRequest): NextResponse {
    const res = intlMiddleware(req) as NextResponse;
    
    const nextLocaleCookie = res.cookies.get("NEXT_LOCALE");
    if (nextLocaleCookie) {
        res.cookies.set({ ...nextLocaleCookie, secure: true })
    }
    return res;
}

export const config = {
    matcher: [
        '/((?!api|_next|_vercel|.*\\..*).*)',
    ],
};


Why do you want it secure? What is the security vulnerability in the current locale?
